# Draw a path with a filled diamond at the beginning

Tags: tikz-pgf

My question is similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50487/tikz-how-to-decorate-a-path-with-the-open-diamond-arrow-tip-that-bends-with-t), but I am trying to draw a simple black filled diamond at the beginning of a path, just like in the [UML aggregate notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738757/uml-aggregation-with-and-without-arrow-head). Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, chains, decorations.markings,intersections,calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (a) at (0,0) {a};
        \node (b) at (2,0) {b};
        \path (a.east) to node [near start, yshift=1em] {} (b.west); 
        \draw [<-,>=diamond] (a.east) -- (b.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

<s>but this produces a path with a diamond that has an arrow at the front, how do I get rid of the arrow?</s>

E.g. turn `<>---->` into `<>----`

**Update:**

It seems I this behaviour is caused by the `tikzset` from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50487/tikz-how-to-decorate-a-path-with-the-open-diamond-arrow-tip-that-bends-with-t) question, which I still had in my code. After removing it, I got the desired behaviour. So I change my question: What causes the arrow had to appear or disappear, and how can I change between both versions?

**Update 2:**
I have updated the question with a MWE and changed the explanation to avoid some of the confusion. The MWE actually produces the desired result of my original question and I am not able to reproduce the problem which I described in the cancelled text. Given all the confusion I think the actual question is this:

**How can I produce each of the following UML variants for aggregation [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738757/uml-aggregation-with-and-without-arrow-head):**

- `<>----` (this is produced by my MWE)
- `<>--->` (arrow at right end)
- `<>---*` (circle at right end)

Comment: Please turn this into a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem as  I can't reproduce the problem you are experiencing.  That is `\draw [<-, >=diamond] (0,0) -- (0,1);` produces the desired results.

Comment: @lanoxx have you had a chance to make a MWE yet?

Comment: @lanoxx The link to "[this]" question is missing.

Comment: Fixed the this link. @Paul: For MWE: Just take the `\tikzset{}` part from the accepted answer under 'this one' and combine it with my sample. You will see that the arrow head will appear.

Comment: @lanoxx, I have done that, and I get `! Package pgf Error: No shape named a is known.` amongst other errors. Please provide a proper MWE so we aren't left guessing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make use of the `arrows` and `arrows.meta` libraries of TikZ. See section 16 in the TikZ Manual. Using this approach you can customize the length, width etc. of the arrow tips as well.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (a) at (0,0) {a};
    \node (b) at (2,0) {b};
    \draw [{Diamond}-] (a.east) -- (b.west);

    \begin{scope}[yshift=-1cm]
      \node (a) at (0,0) {a};
      \node (b) at (2,0) {b};
      \draw [{Diamond}-{Stealth}] (a.east) -- (b.west);
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm]
      \node (a) at (0,0) {a};
      \node (b) at (2,0) {b};
      \draw [{Diamond}-{Circle}] (a.east) -- (b.west);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives the output

[image: Output]

Comment: For more details on the tikz library `arrows.meta`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42679/147179